# Distributed File System Replication Error

Tags: windows-server-2019, dfs-r

We are getting the:

The DFS Replication service stopped replication on the folder with the following local path: C:\Windows\SYSVOL\domain. This server has been disconnected from other partners for 339 days, which is longer than the time allowed by the MaxOfflineTimeInDays parameter (60). DFS Replication considers the data in this folder to be stale, and this server will not replicate the folder until this error is corrected.

There is only a single domain controller, it replaced an older DC but that older DC has been taken offline and recycled, the FSMO roles were properly transferred and the old DC decommissioned. But we are constantly getting this error?

What is it trying to replicate and how do we remove this error?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In ADUC enable View>Advanced Features. Then expand System>DFSR-GlobalSettings>Domain System Volume>Topology and look for the old DC as a member. If it exists there, delete it.

[image]

Comment: Demoting an old DC before removing it from the network takes care of all the details.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but the only DC there is the active DC in use.